# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'PP')

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to display the data from my JSON file.

Here is an idea of the information that is in the JSON => http://jsonblob.com/954388771009478656

In  `DTA` > `PP` , I just want to display the variable `NOMFAMILLE`.

I have an error message:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'PP')
```

In HTML, I have this:

```
 <td class="text-center"> {{ dta.PP.NOMFAMILLE}} </td>
```

In TS,

```
dta ? : Dta;

private getDta(): void {
    let searchDta = new SearchDta(parseInt(this.registreNational + ''), parseInt(this.fiscalYear + ''), parseInt(this.country + ''));
    this.service.getDta(searchDta).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
        if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
            this.dta = res.DTA;
            console.log("Data RES ");
            console.log(this.dta)
        }
    });
}
```

I did a console.log, I get the data.

[image]

Then...

search-dta.response.ts file

```
export interface SearchDtaResponse extends ApiResponse {

    DTA: Dta;
}

export interface Dta {
    PP:  PersonnePhysiqueDta;
    PTF_DTA: PortefeuilleDta[] 

}
export interface PortefeuilleDta {
    CLER: string;
    PAYS: number;
    EXERCICE: number;
    STATUTDTA: number;
    NUMEROSUIVI: number;
}

export interface PersonnePhysiqueDta {
    NOMFAMILLE: string; 
    NUMEROREGISTRENATIONAL: number;
    NATIONALITE: string;

}
```

search-dta.ts file

```
export class SearchDta {
    registreNational: number;
    fiscalYear: number;
    country: number; 

    constructor(
        registreNational: number = 0,
        fiscalYear: number = 0,
        country: number = 0, 
    ) {
        this.registreNational = registreNational;
        this.fiscalYear =  fiscalYear;
        this.country = country

    }
}
```

I don't understand why the `PP` object is not undefined?

[image]

Thank you for your help and your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is being fetched asynchronously, so when the component renders the first time, then `this.dta` is `undefined`, hence the error. You can mitigate this by not rendering the `td` while the data is not there:

```html
<td class="text-center" *ngIf="this.dta"> {{ dta.PP.NOMFAMILLE}} </td>
```

Or, you could even add an extra `ng-content` tag for the value itself and put the `ngIf` on that one (so that the table looks consistent)

```html
<td class="text-center">
  <ng-content *ngIf="this.dta">{{ dta.PP.NOMFAMILLE}}</ng-content>
</td>
```

Another solution to this issue is to use the [optional chaining operator ?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```html
<td class="text-center" *ngIf="this.dta"> {{ dta?.PP?.NOMFAMILLE}} </td>
```